# I am receiving late response "Position" How can solve this problem

Tags: android

I am calling then getting a response but "Position" is reverting late and sometimes not showing data. I can access then on button click event.

My problem is that data is not showing instantly after button click and sometimes it doesn't even show.

```
JSONArray jsonDataArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
if (jsonDataArray != null && jsonDataArray.length() > 0) {
if(whichApiCalled.equalsIgnoreCase("school"))
{
    vectorSchoolData.clear();
    SchoolClass objSchoolData = null;
    schoolArray = new String[jsonDataArray.length()];
    schoolIdArray = new String[jsonDataArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataArray.length(); i++) {
        objSchoolData = new SchoolClass();
        JSONObject objectSchoolData = jsonDataArray.getJSONObject(i);
        objSchoolData.setId(objectSchoolData.getString(getString(R.string.school_id_tag)));
        objSchoolData.setSchoolName(objectSchoolData.getString(getString(R.string.school_name_tag)));
        schoolArray[i] = objSchoolData.getSchoolName();
        schoolIdArray[i] = objSchoolData.getId();
        objSchoolData.setSchoolAddress(objectSchoolData.getString(getString(R.string.school_address_tag)));
        vectorSchoolData.add(objSchoolData);
    }
}
else if(whichApiCalled.equalsIgnoreCase("position"))
{
    Position_TitleClass objPositionTitle = null;
    vectorPositionData.clear();
    positionTitleArray = new String[jsonDataArray.length()];
    positionTitleIdArray = new String[jsonDataArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataArray.length(); i++) {
        objPositionTitle = new Position_TitleClass();
        JSONObject objectPositionData = jsonDataArray.getJSONObject(i);
        objPositionTitle.setPositionTitleId(objectPositionData.getString(getString(R.string.position_title_id_tag)));
        objPositionTitle.setPositionTitleName(objectPositionData.getString(getString(R.string.position_title_name_tag)));
        positionTitleArray[i] = objPositionTitle.getPositionTitleName();
        positionTitleIdArray[i] = objPositionTitle.getPositionTitleId();
        Log.e("Position title is = " , positionTitleArray[i] + " *************");
        vectorPositionData.add(objPositionTitle);
    }
}else if(whichApiCalled.equalsIgnoreCase("team"))
{
    GetTeamsDetailsClass objTeamsDetails = null;
    vectorGetTeamsData.clear();
    teamArray = new String[jsonDataArray.length()];
    teamIdArray = new String[jsonDataArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataArray.length(); i++) {
        objTeamsDetails = new GetTeamsDetailsClass();
        JSONObject objectPositionData = jsonDataArray.getJSONObject(i);
        objTeamsDetails.setTeam_id(objectPositionData.getString(getString(R.string.team_id_tag)));
        objTeamsDetails.setTeam_name(objectPositionData.getString(getString(R.string.team_name_tag)));
        teamArray[i] = objTeamsDetails.getTeam_name();
        teamIdArray[i] = objTeamsDetails.getTeam_id();
        Log.e("team name is = " , teamArray[i] + " *************");
        vectorGetTeamsData.add(objTeamsDetails);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Retrofit for get response fast Instead of this way.